# Populate selectlist with latest 5 years

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist

How am I able to create a list with the last 5 years in it, such as the years `2011` to `2007`. I don't want to hard code the years, but I want the most recent 5 years based on the current year.

Comment: Discover what year it is now, display that plus previous four years. Which part do you have a problem with?

Comment: Any attempts at solving this? Hint: 'DateTime.Today

Answer (score 12):

Put the last 5 years in your view model and bind to that:

```
var last5Years = from n in Enumerable.Range(0,5)
                 select DateTime.Now.Year - n;
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now.Year will give you the current year, then you can use a loop

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   list.Add(dt.Now.Year - i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
List<int> last5Years = new List<int>();
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (int i = currentYear - 5; i < currentYear; i++)
{
    last5Years.Add(i);
}
//databind here
```